# Outlook macro, sending two replies instead of one

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created this macro for Outlook to delete the email upon sending a reply succesfully.

Testing shows that I send two replies instead of one.

```
Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim oExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oOldMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    If oExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Class = olMail Then
        Set oOldMail = oExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Set oMail = oOldMail.Reply
        oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Resolve
        If oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Resolved Then
            'delete reply email from sent items
            oMail.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
            oMail.Send
              'delete original email from inbox
            oOldMail.Delete
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not resolve " & oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Name
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a mail item"
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what the script above does - a message is sent, you grab the selected message and reply to it. Calling Send will trigger ItemSend to fire again. I surprised you do not get into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) is invoked when an Item is about to be sent.

The Item being sent is the Item in "ByVal Item As Object".

You create a second mail with Set oMail = oOldMail.Reply

Even if you now remove Set oMail = oOldMail.Reply and oMail.Send there are other problems with the code.

1. While composing a reply you may do something else and change selections. Set oOldMail = oExplorer.Selection.Item(1) would not get the original mail.
2. For new mail you compose there is no original mail. The last selection you made would be oOldMail and would be deleted.

You need much more sophisticated code to handle these two situations.